# CodeIgniter - showing query result

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, stdclass

Where did i mistake in my code?

controller

```
class uzytkownik extends CI_Controller
{       
    public function index()
    {
        $this -> load -> model('Uzytkownik_model');

        $DaneUzytkownicy = array(
        'Dane' =>  $this -> Uzytkownik_model -> PobierzUzytkownikow(),
        );

        $this -> load -> view('naglowek');
        $this -> load -> view('logo');
        $this -> load -> view('uzytkownicy', $DaneUzytkownicy);
        $this -> load -> view('stopka');
```

model

```
class Uzytkownik_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function PobierzUzytkownikow()
    {
        $ListaUzytkownikow = $this -> db -> query('SELECT * FROM uzytkownik');

        return $ListaUzytkownikow;
    }
```

view

```
foreach ($Dane->result() as $Uzytkownik)
{
    var_dump($Uzytkownik);
    echo $Uzytkownik['id'].' '.$Uzytkownik['imie'].' ' .$Uzytkownik['nazwisko'].'<br>';
}
```

in result i've got

> object(stdClass)#18 (7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["imie"]=> string(3)
>   "Jan" ["nazwisko"]=> string(8) "Kowalski" ["email"]=> string(12)
>   "jan@kowal.pl" ["login"]=> string(5) "Kowal" ["haslo"]=> string(4)
>   "1234" ["data_rejestracji"]=> string(19) "2015-02-23 11:45:48" } 
>   **Fatal error:** Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\views\uzytkownicy.php on line 6

Why fatal error appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `result_array()` instead of `result()` if you want to use the result as an array. Otherwise it will be considered as an object

```
foreach ($Dane->result_array() as $Uzytkownik) {
    var_dump($Uzytkownik);
    echo $Uzytkownik['id'] . ' ' . $Uzytkownik['imie'].' ' . $Uzytkownik['nazwisko'] . '<br>';
}
```

In your case the result `$Uzytkownik` will be an object not an array. so you have to access like this

```
echo $Uzytkownik->id.' '.$Uzytkownik->imie.' '.$Uzytkownik->nazwisko;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use result_array(),because you have to  use as result array,and now you rendred as std object class,

here we go,

```
foreach ($Dane->result_array() as $Uzytkownik)
        {
            var_dump($Uzytkownik);
            echo $Uzytkownik['id'].' '.$Uzytkownik['imie'].' ' .$Uzytkownik['nazwisko'].'<br>';
        }
```